# Initial 'checked' state of radio button with jQuery Mobile + knockout.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I can't seem to figure out why the initial state of my UI doesn't have the first radio button in the `'checked'` state.  Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/floyd_may/JcTxT/

However, this jsFiddle here works just fine, even if you modify it to change it to `radio` inputs (instead of `checkbox`): http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/

You'd start thinking that perhaps jQuery Mobile has a part to play in all this; however, this version of my original fiddle has the jQuery Mobile portions cut out, and still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/floyd_may/JcTxT/5/

Why isn't the 'child 1' radio button initially appearing `checked`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rearranging the order of bindings did it: http://jsfiddle.net/JcTxT/6/

`value: name, checked: $root.selectedName` instead of

`checked: $root.selectedName, value: name`

Comment: That's... infuriating. Hi ho, Hi ho, bug reporting I go! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is apparently a known issue in Knockout.JS: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/552